# rexp_like - can't seem to understand how it works

Tags: sql, regex, oracle12c

I got a table with a "token" column that is supposed to only contain letter, this gets enforced so far with a simple `regexp_like` constraint but recently i noticed a particular problem:
the letter 'a' (lowercase A) is not allowed.
all other standard ASCII letter work as far as i can tell.

Database is:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
 Production PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

```
SELECT CHR(num), num
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[A-Z]+$');
```

using a matching-pattern 'c' or 'i', just using `[a-z]` or other variations give the correct result, but just the simple `[A-Z]` omits the 'a' and only that letter.

Edit:
Yes, using `[a-zA-Z]` would cover all characters, same as using `REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[A-Z]+$', 'i')` ('i' is the match_pattern for case-insensitive), but the question is why is just the lowercase 'a' omitted here.
We generate some other strings and constants from those tokens and have similar constraints all over our database so i do not just want to fix this problem but also understand what caused that.

Comment: Use `[a-zA-Z]` to handle both upper and lower case characters.

Comment: maybe related to collation, compare with sort (order by chr(num))

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, [a-zA-Z] works as expected, same with using any match_patterns, but [A-Z] alone behaves strange and i would like to know what is happening as this regex and similar are used all over our databases.

Comment: What is your database character set, and session language? (On an AL32UTF8 DB and English session your query only lists the 26 uppercase characters as expected; switching the session to German gets 51 results - A-Z and b-z, excluding a...).

Comment: @AlexPoole AL16UTF16

Comment: also could you give all your current nls parameters `select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS`

Comment: nls-param:
```
NLS_LANGUAGE GERMAN`
NLS_TERRITORY GERMANY
NLS_CURRENCY €
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY GERMANY
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ,.
NLS_CALENDAR GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD.MM.RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE GERMAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET UTF8
NLS_SORT GERMAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY €
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Comment: Try `^[\x41-\x5a]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[A-Z]` should only include uppercase characters, and exclude all lower-case ones. At least, that's what it should - and does - do in English, with binary sorting:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'ENGLISH';

select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';

PARAMETER                      VALUE                                   
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_SORT                       BINARY                                  

SELECT CHR(num), num
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[A-Z]+$');

C        NUM
- ----------
A         65
...
Z         90

26 rows selected.
```

In German (or any other language that modifies the default sort order) it does what I think you're describing:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'GERMAN';

select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';

PARAMETER                      VALUE                                   
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_SORT                       GERMAN                                  

SELECT CHR(num), num
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[A-Z]+$');

C        NUM
- ----------
A         65
...
X         88
Y         89
Z         90
b         98
c         99
d        100
...
z        122
```

Switching to character classes makes it behave more consistently:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'GERMAN';

SELECT CHR(num), num
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[[:upper:]]+$');

C        NUM
- ----------
A         65
...
Z         90

26 rows selected.
```

If you want to include all upper and lowercase characters then you can use `[:alpha:]` instead of `[:upper:]`. Note that either of these will include diacritics (and `lower` or `alpha` will include 'ß'); which may or may not be desirable:

```
SELECT character
FROM (
  SELECT CHR(LEVEL + 64) AS character
  FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 58
  UNION ALL SELECT column_value
  FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('ß', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü'))
)
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(character, '^[[:upper:]]+$')
ORDER BY character;

CHARACTER
---------
A
Ä
B
...
```

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-A7ABC638-4928-40F7-A252-6A1B84482BD5).

> Traditional regular expression engines were designed to address only English text. However, regular expression implementations can encompass a wide variety of languages with characteristics that are very different from western European text. The implementation of regular expressions in Oracle Database is based on the Unicode Regular Expression Guidelines. The REGEXP SQL functions work with all character sets that are supported as database character sets and national character sets. Moreover, Oracle Database enhances the matching capabilities of the POSIX regular expression constructs to handle the unique linguistic requirements of matching multilingual data.

and

> According to the POSIX standard, a range in a regular expression includes all collation elements between the start point and the end point of the range in the linguistic definition of the current locale. Therefore, ranges in regular expressions are meant to be linguistic ranges, not byte value ranges ...
>
> ... Oracle Database interprets range expressions as specified by the NLS_SORT parameter to determine the collation elements covered by a given range

[Linguistic collation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-C8379BCB-B175-40E3-8824-59C20F92C864) is essentially based on how languages behave, or are expected to behave by their users.

If you have a binary sort then characters are ordered based purely on the code point (ASCII/Unicode value) of each character; 'a' is 97, which is obviously after (numerically higher than) 'A' which is 65. If you select all the characters and use a binary sort you see:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'GERMAN';
alter session set nls_sort = 'BINARY';

SELECT CHR(LEVEL + 64) AS character, NLSSORT(CHR(LEVEL + 64)) AS sort
FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 58
UNION ALL SELECT column_value, NLSSORT(column_value)
FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('ß', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü'))
ORDER BY character;

CHARACTER SORT     
--------- ---------
A         4100     
B         4200     
C         4300     
...
X         5800     
Y         5900     
Z         5A00     
[         5B00     
\         5C00     
]         5D00     
^         5E00     
_         5F00     
`         6000     
a         6100     
b         6200     
c         6300    
... 
x         7800     
y         7900     
z         7A00     
Ä         C38400   
Ö         C39600   
Ü         C39C00   
ß         C39F00   
ä         C3A400   
ö         C3B600   
ü         C3BC00   

65 rows selected.
```

[The `nlssort()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NLSSORT.html) lets you see the actual value Oracle is using for the sorting - here it's the binary value for the characters, so 'A' is still 65 (well, 41 as it's in hex) plus a null byte. When you order by those 'a' is still after 'A'.

With linguistic collation those sort values are completely different:

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'GERMAN';

SELECT CHR(LEVEL + 64) AS character, NLSSORT(CHR(LEVEL + 64)) AS sort
FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 58
UNION ALL SELECT column_value, NLSSORT(column_value)
FROM TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('ß', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü'))
ORDER BY character;

CHARACTER SORT     
--------- ---------
[         00005B00 
\         00005C00 
]         00005D00 
^         00005E00 
_         00005F00 
`         00006000 
a         14000100 
A         14000200 
ä         14000900 
Ä         14000A00 
b         19000100 
B         19000200 
c         1E000100 
C         1E000200 
...
r         64000100 
R         64000200 
s         69000100 
S         69000300 
ß         69004400 
t         6E000100 
T         6E000200 
u         73000100 
U         73000200 
ü         73000900 
Ü         73000A00 
v         78000100 
V         78000200 
w         7A000100 
W         7A000200 
x         7D000100 
X         7D000200 
y         82000100 
Y         82000200 
z         87000100 
Z         87000200 

65 rows selected.
```

The 'linguistic' part means that all variations of 'a' are together - 'a', 'A', 'ä' and 'Ä', in that order. Then all the 'b' variations, etc., with language-specific characters grouped with their generic relations. There is much more about this in the documentation, [including examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-B84E044F-C147-483B-957B-12EBDB368D3F).

The behaviour you're seeing is explained by that ordering. Look again at the start of that sorted list:

```
CHARACTER SORT     
--------- ---------
...
a         14000100 
A         14000200 
ä         14000900 
Ä         14000A00 
b         19000100 
B         19000200 
c         1E000100 
C         1E000200
```

If you try to use a regular expression with a range of `[A-Z]` then it starts at 'A', but in this collation order that is *after* 'a' - so that lower-case 'a' is excluded. Similarly, if you use `[B-Z]` then you start from 'B', which is after all the 'a' variants and lowercase 'b', so that is now excluded.

Comment: That explains what should be done but it does not explain why the lowercase 'a' is not included in the range, even more so as i noticed that `[B-Z]`does not include the small 'b' either - somehow with language set to German it just cuts of the first letter of the lowercase range (that should not be included anyways).

Comment: @ABaumstumpf - I've added further explanation, but I'd suggest you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html) to get a fuller understanding of what Oracle is doing.

Answer (score 1):

could reproduce doing following

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = FRENCH;

SELECT CHR(num), num FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[a-z]+$')
order by CHR(num);
```

compare with

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = BINARY;

SELECT CHR(num), num FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200
) WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CHR(num), '^[a-z]+$')
order by CHR(num);
```

it seems that regexp character set is following the NLS_SORT parameter

Comment: So you're saying a-z is not in the 0x41-0x5a range ?

Comment: @sin - that's only relevant with a binary sort. With a linguistic sort it isn't using a byte range, it's using a linguistic range. (See the docs I quoted).

Comment: @AlexPoole  - Oh, I get it. If I use a regex with a character byte like `\x5a` it will match comma or something else. Does the regex engine they use actually interpret constructs like byte or does it randomly choose something with a different meaning ?

Comment: Oh, that would explain a lot, but really strange behaviour.

Comment: Note that specifying third argument `'c'` for case sensitive NLS parameters are no more used, seems to be a better practice than to use a function which depends on regional parameters. (A little like using to_date with/without format(and depending on NLS_DATE_FORMAT)